# Update uitableviewcell image

Tags: ios, image, dynamic, uitableview

View 1:

> Have tableview with eight rows.when user select a particular row it will move to view2

View2:

> open the camera and when user take a photo,it should navigate to view1.
>   And in view1 selected row cell image should get updated with the image taken using camera.

My questions:

1. How can i send a image to view1 and how can i store the image of eight rows?I need this image temporaily only. Array ? tmp folder with in app? which is the best way?
2. How can i update the cell image when return from view2?

Answer (score 1):

Delegation. You should use delegation to send the image back to view1. Create a protocol in view2 that defines a method something like:

```
-(void)imageCaptured:(UIImage*)image;
```

Then create a variable in view2 like:

```
@property id<view2Protocol> delegate;
```

Now implement that protocol in view1 by adding:

```
view1 : UIView <view2Protocol>
```

to the class definition and defining the imageCaptured method.
Then, in view1, set view2's delegate property to self when you're presenting view2. Then when you capture an image in view2, call:

```
[self.delegate imageCaptured:capturedImage]
```

and perform whatever logic you need to set the image to the cell.

Just as a side note: you really should have viewControllers managing all this interaction, rather than views.